# Python wifi subprocess & communication errors

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, wifi, putty

I am trying to connect to a romba robot via wifi. I have successfully been able to use the below code to open the cmd and connect to the wifi and send its password. This connects the bot and the computer successfully. My problem is when I try to send additional information. I am only attempting to pass one character at a time.

I am using the subprocess and pipe functionality to send data, but when I try to use this a second time, it gives me the error "Cannot send input after starting communication" Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

```
#Connects the the desired WiFi network.         
def connect_to_network(name):

    global Network
    #global Putty

    Network = Popen('netsh wlan connect ' + str(name), shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, stdin=PIPE)

    password = "password"
    Network.communicate(input=password.encode('utf-8'))
    Network.stdin.close()

     #Putty = Application(backend="uia").start('putty.exe -raw 192.168.1.1')



#Sends out character to BOT via WiFi.
def WiFi_Send(action):

    global Network
    #global Putty

    clear_output()

    print("Sending: " + str(action))

    #PACKET TO SEND
    packet = ""

    if(action == "SCAN"):
        packet = "S"
    elif(action == "MOVE FORWARD"):
        packet = "F"
    elif(action == "TURN LEFT"):
        packet = "L"
    elif(action == "TURN RIGHT"):
        packet = "R"

     Network.communicate(input=packet.encode('utf-8'))
     Network.stdin.close()
```

output:

```
Sending: SCAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c2f5d752b649> in <module>()
    341 #   call in value. (Waits for it to start)
    342 if __name__ == "__main__":
 -->343    main()

<ipython-input-2-c2f5d752b649> in main()
    326                     buttonFlag = 0
    327                     actionComplete = True
--> 328                     WiFi_Send(action)
    329                     break
330                 elif(B_button):

<ipython-input-2-c2f5d752b649> in WiFi_Send(action)
    172         packet = "R"
    173 
--> 174     Network.communicate(input=packet.encode('utf-8'))
    175     Network.stdin.close()
    176 

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in communicate(self, input, timeout)
    811 
    812         if self._communication_started and input:
--> 813             raise ValueError("Cannot send input after starting 
communication")
    814 
    815         # Optimization: If we are not worried about timeouts, we haven't

ValueError: Cannot send input after starting communication
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that you're reusing the same `Network` object in both routines.

The issue is that `communicate` only works once. It's a convenient method to get separate output & error streams and hide the complexity of deadlock avoidance when consuming those streams.

You cannot use `communicate` more than once on a `subprocess.Popen` object. If you want to feed input to your program you should do:

```
Network.stdin.write(password.encode('utf-8'))
```

And of course don't close the input stream:

<s>`Network.stdin.close()`</s>

don't forget to follow by a linefeed

```
Network.stdin.write(b"\n")
```

I also suggest that you don't use `stdout=PIPE` but leave the default (or redirect to nothing with `stdout=DEVNULL` so the output buffer doesn't gets full & blocks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the follow up! I am getting a new error caused by the .write you suggested. Please look back at my post for the updated error! Once again I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: I have reverted to my edit because 1) my answer was wrong (input= should be removed) and 2) I had edited the explanation to make it shorter & clearer. Tell me if it works from comments unless it's absolutely necessary to edit the question.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so so much Jean! You solved an issue ive been banging my head at for 10+ hours! I truly mean thank you and I appreciate your guidance on how to ask better questions in the future! Thanks again!

Comment: If you dont mind me asking a follow up question quickly, how would i go about reading in data from the network? Would Network.stdout.read() work?

Comment: yes, but you would have to reinstate `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`. Now you have 2 channels: 1 in and 1 out. If the process writes too much in a row while you're not consuming the output, you could deadlock. This kind of thing is better done in another thread if you encounter problems.

Comment: By another thread you mean I would make a second instance of "network" but set stdin to DEVNULL?

Comment: no, use the same `Network` variable, but in another thread that would consume the output and put it in a python list you could read from in the other thread. That would avoid deadlocks. But first try the naïve approach. Depending on your executable, that could work.